# Wireless WIFI is disabled and the system stutter after an update in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 20.04, updates, hp

After installing ubuntu 20.04 (dual boot with windows 10), I've connected to WIFI and ran "Software Updater". After a reboot, the system is Unable to detect any WIFI networks and started to freeze every few moments (if i stroke a key while writing, e.g. "b", it will write "bbbb" when the system become responsive again.
moreover the WIFI icon disappear and reappear every few seconds. **Ubuntu runs fine before any updates**

I have installed Ubuntu again several more times and found out:

1. The problem only emerges when updating the packages of "Ubuntu base" under the "Security
   updates" in Software Updater.
2. If during the OS installation process the system does connect to a network, the problem will
   emerge as if the problematic package was installed (even when choosing minimal installation).

It's worth mentioning that:

1. My machine is: "HP Pavilion Gaming Desktop TG01-2xxx"
2. Secure boot is disabled.
3. It can only boot with the boot kernel parameter "noapic".
4. When using the boot kernel parameter "acpi=off" the system manages to detects WIFI networks but
   the task monitor shows only 1 CPU (instead of 12) and the system is very slow.

I would really appreciate your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem.

The wifi adapter i was using (Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX201) requires kernel 5.2+ but the Ubuntu version i was using (20.04) uses in default 5.13.
It is possible to change the kernel version in the grub menu by choosing "Advanced options for Ubuntu".

An important step is to install the Kernel extras before switching to 5.4 kernel so to have internet access at all.
For my kernel version i had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-99-generic
```

Odd thing: Before installing the kernel extras, my system was able to boot even without the "noapic" kernel option, after installing the extras, I had to put back "noapic" for the system to boot.